# How to modify a specific folder icon?

Tags: raspbian

[image]There is a default icon for the Music folder. Now, I made a Sounds folder, and I want to set the icon for it to the icon for the Music folder's icon. How can I do that?

Comment: what is the red mess supposed to show?

Comment: @jsotola Attempted obfuscation :)

Answer (score 1):

These fancy folder icons are assigned via [XDG user directories](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/XDG_user_directories) configuration. AFAIK you can't have several directories of the same type, but you can certainly assing your own directory on the existing type, e.g.

```
XDG_MUSIC_DIR="$HOME/Sounds"
```

should apply the music icon on the "Sounds" folder (and the default icon on the Music folder).